# How do I insert a java List<String> using Mybatis?

Tags: java, ibatis, mybatis

I would like to insert a list of strings into a single column in my database using Mybatis.  I've tried using a Custom TypeHandler but I can't even get Mybatis to invoke it.

For a more detailed report on what I've already done click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762471/how-do-configure-the-dao-files-to-handle-inserting-a-liststring-in-mybatis)

Comment: have you read this http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html#typeHandlers article?

Comment: not specifically but I will, it looks like a good starting spot.  I am somewhat familiar with TypeHandlers...my question is how to do get Mybatis to invoke the typehandler I need when doing an INSERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While specifying parameters for `INSERT` statement do like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableName(a) VALUES(#{aVal, typeHandler=com.test.YourTypeHandler})
```

where `aVal` is the parameter that you have passed to statement. Also intead of full name of typehandler you can use it alias. But don't forget to register it(typeHandler) in configuration file of MyBatis

**edited**

A good practise is  specifying a type of value to be inserted like this:
`#{aVal, jdbcType=VARCHAR, typeHandler=com.test.YourTypeHandler}`. It will save you from issues with null values of aVal

Comment: I've asked this question three different ways on two different sites...you're the first to answer and your answer works perfectly.  Thank you so much.  If anyone reads this please mark this answer as useful, it is well deserved.  This is what makes stackoverflow so great!